# Java method - missing return statement

Tags: java, android

So I've found a lot of examples on this issue, but the method to fix it seems to differ. So here I am looking for a solution to my specific problem.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.frederik.snapsule;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LoginButton login;
    TextView info;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    //Creating and initializing the feature(Code from Facebook install guide)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); //Calls for the facebook feature
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

        // Callback registration
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At the second last "}" I get the error "Missing return statement", but to my eyes it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OncreateView` has return type of `View`, So you must return a view which attached to activity.

If you are Overriding `onCreate` method you may not needed to override `OnCreateView` method. in `onCreate` method you can use `setContentView(R.layout.content_main)`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Callback registration
    login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
    /**
     *return view 
     */
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Actually getting a "onCreateView" is never used, so I seem to have an issue there

Comment: This is really bad advice! First of all `onCreate` and `onCreateView` do very different things, also `setContentView` is not available in fragments.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar please check Code, It is Activity as far as i see.

Answer (score 1):

The method to fix this error is always the same: The error occurs when a method has a return type and not all code paths return a value of that type. The `onCreateView` method is supposed to return a `View`, which in your case it does not. You are *inflating* the view into the `view` variable, but you never *return* that value.

Change your code to:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Callback registration
    login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });

    return view; // <<< THIS IS IT
}
```

Comment: It worked! Just a quick side-question, The @Override above onCreateView  gives me the "method does not overrule its superclass" error. Can I just remove that, or would that result in that part of code not being run?

Comment: @Stenberg, The `@Override` annotation has no effect. It is used to ensure you are overriding a superclass method or implementing an interface method. If you define a new method with the Override annotation on it, you will get a compile time error. It is a good practice to use the annotation to avoid some mistakes when you are overriding methods but you can safely remove the annotation if you want.

Comment: Usually the error you're seeing occurs when you "override" a method that is not part of the super class. Many times this occurs when you spell the method name wrong (casing).

Answer (score 1):

At First Add this `return view;`

```
  @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
    return view;//Add this 
}
```

Where is **setContentView** ?

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); //Calls for the facebook feature
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return statement as stated below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Callback registration
    login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
    return view;//view must be returned from this method
}
```